# How to change Kentico CMS 9 root page title?

Tags: customization, kentico

The root page of a newly created Kentico CMS 9 site (based on the Blank template) has a title of "My Site -/" None of the explanations I have found on how to change this seem to apply. It's probably staring me in the face, but so far I have missed it.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 3):

Admin > Settings > Content --> Scroll down to Metadata and its the Page Title Format field.  Remember that you can either select Global (will affect all sites hosted) or the specific site

Comment: And also the Page Title Prefix field below it

Comment: Chetan, Virgil: thanks much for the clear directions. As the old saying goes, I was lost (in the interface) but now I am found. Yey!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure the page title, you have a choice of the following methods:

A:  Go to the CMS Desk and select the document in the content tree. Now open Properties -> Metadata and set the document page title in the Page title field.

B: The page title format will be generated according to the configuration in Site Manager – Settings -  - Content  - Page title format. If for example, you would like to check if the document has a unique page title and, if so, to display only this title

This will display a default value if the Page title in the Metadata section is empty. Otherwise, it displays the page title from the Metadata section.